# How to stop my brother's MitM attack

Tags: networking, man-in-the-middle

My brother's repeatedly locking my computer with his phone using a man-in-the-middle attack and screwing up my DNS cache.

How can I get my computer to refuse to interact with 192.168.0.65 and prevent him from messing around?

Comment: Bonus points if you can tell me how to screw with him in return.

Comment: With absolutely no information about which operating system of your computer and his phone there is no absolute answer to that. And for your bonus question: I don't know how such requests are handled in here but I will definitely not give you an answer to that.

Comment: Do you know how he is achieving the MitM?  Is he using ARP spoofing?  Does he have control of your router?  Is he physically in the middle between you and the internet connection?  How are you connected?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, he's got some Android phone, no idea what he's using there. I don't know how he's MitM'ing, but I'm connected by WiFi. He is physically in between me and the router.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I edited your post and title to save you from the downvotes. While this is a decent question (it does need more detail as suggested in the above comments), profanity and insults are not allowed, and generally lead to downvotes. If you feel you can improve my edit, feel free.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a true man in the middle attack . . . man in the middle would imply that all your traffic is going through his Android phone.  What exactly are you seeing happening on your system?

Comment: This is a man in the middle attach, the phone is broadcasting the same Wi-Fi SSID and the laptop is connecting the phone instead of the router.

Comment: @heavyd ah, I missed the comment thread where the OP clarified why it was a man in the middle, and not a remote exploit . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't **stop** a MITM attack without physically disconnecting the computer/person/software performing the MITM (have you tried kicking 'em where it hurts?).

What you *can* do is make an end-to-end connection to a remote host *tamper-evident*, meaning, you would be able to know if either (a) your brother is listening in, or (b) modifying the contents of the connection. That's what SSL/TLS is for.

Set up a free micro instance on Amazon AWS and run OpenVPN in it. Only trust it if the server cert verification succeeds. You can do the setup entirely over SSL (https://aws.amazon.com at first, then SSH) then tunnel all your other traffic over it. If you get certificate warnings, you know you're being MITMed. If you've already exhausted bursting into his room and unplugging his computer from the wall socket, or turning off power to his room at the house's circuit breaker, at least you will be able to sit around and wait until he stops trying to modify/eavesdrop your traffic by foregoing any internet activity while the VPN server certificate fails verification.

All SSL / TLS / PKI systems operate under the assumption that your local trusted root CA store is secure, so if he is able to gain physical access to your computer, all bets are off -- he can install a root CA that he has the signing key for, and your browser will be none the wiser (it won't give you any errors or anything; you'd have to manually examine the trust chain to be able to tell, and in the worst case, you'd have to obtain the root CA of the site you're SSLing into using a reliable channel, and compare the exact public key bytes to the root CA on your computer.)

The best way of course would be to get your own internet connection, maybe a 4G cellular connection, and deny him access to the gateway/hardware (whatever device is chiefly responsible for connecting to the 4G network). Assuming that he's unable to physically gain control of the hardware somehow, you'd be safe then.

Comment: Thanks for the surprisingly detailed answer considering my obviously ranting question. I guess the main reason I'm irritated is because once he turns off WiFi on his phone, I lose all internet access until the computer finally realises that he's not there anymore...

Comment: Is there maybe anything in the firewall I can set to prevent his device from being able to talk to my computer?

Comment: "The firewall"? On what? Your cable modem? Your computer? If all your traffic is being routed through his phone, that's probably being done by setting a traffic forwarding rule on the upstream router, of which both his phone and your computer are clients. If you don't have access to the router, there's really nothing you can do. Your computer's firewall *probably* isn't responsible for this forwarding, unless he has physical access to your computer (knows your password, etc).

Comment: It sounds like you're actually connecting to his Wi-Fi and not your router.  Do you have WPA setup on your router, if not you should, but he can still broadcast an evil Wi-Fi signal with the same password.

Comment: It is seeming that way, yeah... I guess his phone is pretending to be an extender of the network, because a tracert is going through his phone before getting to the router.

Comment: I dont know how sophisticated the network connection manager in Windows 7 is but in Windows XP you can interfere a wifi which is secured by WPA with an open wifi and your computer automatically connects to the strongest one with the same name. Look at my answer above for a bit of clarification.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Why not just reset the router to defaults and set up a proper WiFi network from the ground up? That would eliminate any spoofing he's set up.

Comment: @Moses, his laptop is connecting directly to the Android phone, messing with the router is not going to stop the attack, unless he changes the SSID of the wireless network, but then brother can just change to match.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your computer to stop interacting with 192.168.0.65 just add a rule to the windows firewall. This will stop him for a while but just blocking a IP-Address will not be sufficient. The more reliable way is to begin with what @allquxotic stated in his answer.

Maybe your brother just named a wifi exactly like the one you normally connect to but when he's physically near you the signal of his wifi is stronger so your computer connects to it instead of the one you intend to connect. If this is the case you must set the BSSID of the wifi access point manually in your network configuration so your computer only connects to the right wifi.

Answer (score -1):

You need to statically assign your IP address in your router, then set strict rules regarding the gateway, ie. only communicate w/ xyz. Even if you use tls/ssl, he can use the cipher exchange to decrypt traffic. Sounds like he is playing games and injecting frames into your html content. Setting up static routes between your pc and the router will stop that. Lets say you do not set up the static route, and let us let him continue on being deviant. Under windows you can always check the route you machine is taking by issuing the command route print in prompt. This should return your gateways address, ie. 192.168./1, 172.16/1 or 10./1. If its not a 1 at the end of those numbers you have found your brother.